# Spring SimpleFormController in 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i notice that this controller has now been deprecated in the latest spring and was wondering what the alternative controller is?

Comment: Bear in mind that wile the deprecated stuff still works in Spring 3, the Spring guys are much more aggressive in removing deprecated APIs than the JavaSE people, i.e they actually will remove them.

Comment: Yup `SimpleFormController` is no longer supported (tried with `4.0.4.RELEASE`).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Spring 3.0 you should use simple classes annotated by `@Controller`. Such controller can handle more than one request. Each request is handled by its own method. These methods are annotated by `@RequestMapping`.

One thing you need to rethink is the fact, that a old school `SimpleFormController` handle a lot of different requests (at least: one to get the form and a second to submit the form). You have to handle this now by hand. But believe me it is easier.

For example this Controller in REST Style, will handle two requests:

- /book - POST: to create a book
- /book/form - GET: to get the form for creation

Java Code:

```
@RequestMapping("/book/**")
@Controller
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(
        @ModelAttribute("bookCommand") final BookCommand bookCommand) {

        Book book = createBookFromBookCommand(bookCommand);
        return "redirect:/book/" + book.getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/book/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createForm(final ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("all", "what you need");
        return "book/create"; //book/create.jsp
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers. annotaing mapping is all new to me as i was following this book i got http://www.amazon.co.uk/Spring-Action-Craig-Walls/dp/1933988134/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1295447914&sr=8-1

Comment: quick question. does that mean i no longer have to map my controllers into beans via xml files?

Comment: @jonney: Yes, there are new Annotations: @Controller, @Service, @Repository, as well as @Autowire and @Inject. But you have to enable something that is called component scan in your xml. - Have a look at the SpringSource blog (around end of 2009) and the new features section of the Spring reference. -- You are also free to ask a new question.

Comment: awsome. this way is definitely easier! i'l have a look at the other annotations in spring.

Answer (score 6):

[Annotated POJOs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html) can act as controllers; see `@Controller`.

Comment: Why on earth was this voted down, a year and a half after it was posted?  Were the other answers voted down as well?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 3.0, your Controllers should no longer inherit from a base class.
The standard way is to use [annotated controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller).

Comment: So i dont have to map my controllers via xml anymore aint it?

Comment: @jonney exactly. the XML way to do it is not even documented anymore in the Spring 3 Reference.

Comment: what about for DI and aspects? all can be defined using annotations now? is there any need to write any spring bean anymore lol?

Comment: @jonney there are ApplicationContext implementations that don't need XML at all, e.g. [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html). But usually, some XML is required (and with Springsource Tool Suite, managing the XML is actually fun)