# SimpleFormController - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command'

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my basic spring mvc application I am getting the exception. I am using `SimpleFormController`. My code is as below.

In my dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
           <!-- <prop key="login.htm">loginController</prop>  -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
<!--  <bean name="loginController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="login"/>  -->

 <bean name="/login.htm" class="com.pack.controller.LoginController" >
 <property name="commandClass" value="com.pack.model.User" />
 <property name="formView" value="login"/>
 <property name="successView" value="index.htm"/>
 </bean>
```

In my JSP page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form:form name="loginForm" method="post">
        ${msg}
        <form:input id="username" path="username"/>
        <form:password id="password" path="password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" />
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my controller class

```
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController{

    @Override
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws ServletException {
        User user =  (User)command;
        System.out.println("Username:" + user.getUsername() + " Password:" + user.getPassword());
        if(user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("sa") && user.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase("12")){
            return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
        }
        else
        {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
            modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Invalid login");
            return  modelAndView;
        }
    }    
}
```

Once the user enter correct username and password will redirect to the `index` page. This is working properly. But the user enter wrong login credentials it throws this error.

> exception
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
>   root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for this problem,If we use HTML controls rather than spring controls, this issue will solve.Here in JSP file,

```
 <%--   <form:input id="username" path="username"/>
        <form:password id="password" path="password"/> --%>
        <input type="text" name="username"/> 
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
```

This will solve the issue.Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 4):

You can reference the spring form tag documentation here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.form

The culprit is that you are not setting the 'modelAttribute' attribute, which gets defaulted to 'command'; hence, your error message.  You should set 'modelAttribute' to the name of the attribute in your model which represents a User.

Also, I agree with micha that you should use the newer annotation based controllers.

Below you will find an example of how to properly use modelAttribute.  Notice that when you a request gets routed to users/new, the Controller places an empty user (new User()) into the model under the 'user' key.  The JSP then specifies 'user' as the modelAttribute (I'm fairly sure this is case sensitive).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());

        return "users/new";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(User user) {
        this.userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/users/" + user.getId();
    }

}
```

Inside "users/new.jsp":

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<html>

<body>
<c:url value="/users" var="users"/>

<sf:form action="${users}" method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="full_name">Full Name:</label></th>
            <td><sf:input path="name" size="15" id="full_name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User" />
</sf:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Let me check it.

Comment: This is not working.I have changed the code as like this in JSP file                                                       <form:form name="loginForm" method="post" modelAttribute="User"> .But getting an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'User' available as request attribute"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a real answer to your problem but you should use (newer) annotation based controllers if possible. You are using `SimpleFormController` which is deprecated in the current spring version.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734259/spring-simpleformcontroller-in-3-0) or [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/) for an alternative.

Comment: thanks for the answer.But I am looking for the solution this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid solution, rather a work-around, as the binding to your command object would not be available.

In a similar error situation, I found out that the commandName in my *-servlet.xml was differrent. When I made it identical to the actual commandBean, the error had disappeared.