# Error while using annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am a newbie to advanced java and learning Spring framework. I found one tutorial

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html

In the code below

```
package contoller;

import java.net.BindException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import service.HelloService;
/**
*
* @author Manish
*/
public class HelloController extends SimpleFormController {

public HelloController() {
setCommandClass(Name.class);
setCommandName("name");
setSuccessView("helloView");
setFormView("nameView");
}
 private HelloService helloService;
 public void setHelloService(HelloService helloService) {
 this.helloService = helloService;
  }

@Override          // Error Method does not override or implment a method of supertype
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object command,
        BindException errors) throws Exception {

    Name name = (Name) command;
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
    mv.addObject("helloMessage", helloService.sayHello(name.getValue()));
    return mv;
  }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Regards.

Comment: Can you post the whole class?

Comment: What is use of annotation in framework?

Comment: @override is not spring annotation. It just indicates that method is an overriden method from super class. Your super class `SimpleFormController ` dont have a method with signature `protected ModelAndView onSubmit(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object command,
        BindException errors) throws Exception`

Comment: If i remove this, will it be ok to use. I think it will throw an error. If there is no method in this class then we should not override it.

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734259/spring-simpleformcontroller-in-3-0

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Method does not override or implment a method of supertype

This is not related to Spring. It says in your `SimpleFormController` class there is no method `onSubmit`.

Add this method to your `SimpleFormController` class and the problem is solved.

Comment: There is a onSubmit Method available in SimpleFormController class.